# TransBank WebPay | Send money to another TransBank Webpay customer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a PHP Codeigniter Application and it uses TransBank WebPay API for Payments.

Can I send money to another TransBank WebPay customer through the integrated TransBank WebPay API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer through TransBank Webpay support. They actually do not support money transfer between customers.